# how to authorize only flutter app in djano server?

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart

While I'm using Django as my backend and flutter as my front end. I want only the flutter app to access the data from django server. Is there any way to do this thing?

Like we use allowed host can we do something with that?

Comment: Yes you have to create some views on your django site which can return your response in a Json format and then you can present that data on your flutter app. you can use Django JsonResponse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/ or Django rest framework for that https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: @ShavaizHussain I already completed all the things I just nee to know to allow or authorize only my app user

Answer (score 1):

You can use an authentication method for it. Only allow for the users authenticated from your flutter app to use your backend.

Comment: If you are working with DRF, the authentication view will return a token and when your application queries your API you will need to add the `Authorization` header with the token.